# Change collapse data-target and id automatically

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Inside an ng-repeat I have a table in which I display information using Bootstap collapse, however I need the id to be changed with the loop in order for the data to be displayed in the right place, with my current code it keeps displaying in the same row with each click, here is my code :

```
 <tr ng-repeat=" p in projetsListe ">
       <td>{{p.NomProjet}}</td>
       <td>{{calcul(p.IdProjet)}}</td>
       <td>{{calculTotal(p.IdProjet)}}</td>
       <td>{{calcul(p.IdProjet)-calculTotal(p.IdProjet)}}</td>
       <td>
         <a href="#" ng-click="myFunction(p.IdProjet)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            <span>Voir les détails</span> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul id="d" class="collapse"> 
              <table id= "mytable" class="table table-hover" style="display : none;">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Tache</th>
                <th><center>Charge estimée</center></th>
                <tr ng-repeat="t in tempnorep">
                <td>{{t.NomTache}}</td>
                <td><center>{{t.TempsPrevu}} jours<center></td>
                </tr> 
              </table>
            </ul>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you specify which `id` you want to change?

Comment: @HasanIbrahim data-target="#d" and id="d"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you wanted to do something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat=" p in projetsListe ">
       <td>{{p.NomProjet}}</td>
       <td>{{calcul(p.IdProjet)}}</td>
       <td>{{calculTotal(p.IdProjet)}}</td>
       <td>{{calcul(p.IdProjet)-calculTotal(p.IdProjet)}}</td>
       <td>
         <a href="#" ng-click="myFunction(p.IdProjet)" data-toggle="collapse" ng-attr-data-target="#{{p.IdProjet}}">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            <span>Voir les détails</span> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul ng-attr-id="{{p.IdProjet}}" class="collapse"> 
              <table id= "mytable" class="table table-hover" style="display : none;">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Tache</th>
                <th><center>Charge estimée</center></th>
                <tr ng-repeat="t in tempnorep">
                <td>{{t.NomTache}}</td>
                <td><center>{{t.TempsPrevu}} jours<center></td>
                </tr> 
              </table>
            </ul>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it works now, it was the display : none that was causing the problem